# How to use sd() function in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In laravel 4, I use sd() function for print value of variable but I can't use it in laravel 5.

Code

```
sd($entry);
```

Error

```
Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\sd()
```

What is namespace to use?

Comment: Is there such funciton? Are you sure it is not user defined function or comes from third packages

Comment: you mean dd() ? :)

Comment: I think you meant `dd()` which is dump and die.

Comment: Thanks guys,I use dd() instead sd() it work. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **dd($value);** for print value. Dump and die.

```
laravel 4: dd($value);

laravel 5: dd($value);
```

Same use for laravel 4 & 5.

You can check here doc:

Laravel 4: [laravel 4](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/helpers#miscellaneous)

Laravel 5: [laravel 5](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-dd)

Comment: Welcome :) @saranchomphuphan